# ASP.NET MVC: Html.AntiForgeryToken gives the same token on each page load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

On my local machine, the Html.AntiForgeryToken method sets the value of the __RequestVerificationToken hidden field to a new, totally random string every time I reload the form. But if I move the same code to the remote server, the value of that hidden field is the same. It stays the same even if I recycle the app pool or clear run time cache by changing something in web.config. What did I do wrong?

Comment: do you have any caching servers or proxies?

Comment: Nope. Just a regular Win 2003 server, .NET 4.0, IIS 6

Answer (score 0):

Probably, a machine key is defined in web.config , take a look : [How To Configure MachineKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx) , and this cause to generate same  Anti Forgery Token .May be the server is overriding to machine key.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope. That wasn't it. Thanks for the answer, though :)